# nginx redirect TLD to TLD with virtual folder (example.com => example.com/test)

Tags: nginx, web-server, configuration

I'm running nginx and in the config file I need to always have the domain example.com redirect to example.com/test. I tried various methods for achieving this but I always got a redirect error.

**EDIT:** It's worth mentioning that I **only** want example.com to redirect to example.com/test. I don't want example.com/something to have /test in the url.

What is the correct way to do this?

This is a snippet of my current nginx.conf:

```
server {
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  location / {
    rewrite ^.+ /test permanent;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  location / {
    root /var/www/apps/example/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why have you got two `server` blocks with the same `server_name`? NGINX will only process the first one it comes to

Comment: I edited out some of the domains for simplicity. The last server_name field includes another domain as well. Basically, there are two domains, each pointing to the same CMS. The CMS then displays the correct domain based on virtual folder name. It removed it so that people wouldnt get confused.

Comment: @Amund Each `server_name` should only occur in *ONE* server block. I.E. example.com can only be in one server block regardless of how many other domains you have

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because I`ve gotten redirects to work perfectly fine with two server blocks. For instance the first one redirects www.example.com to example.com and the second block is for the actual application.

Comment: @Amund Yes, NGINX will only process a single server block, the first one it finds and ignore all others

Comment: I did some research and the proper way is to use two server blocks. I also tried a few different variations and I managed to get it to redirect, but it redirected to /testtesttesttesttesttesttest etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not remember, but somehow the right way:

```
server {
    server_name  example.com;
    rewrite ^/$ http://www.example.com/test   permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

samarudge is right - you should have only one `server` block.
Try putting `root`, `passenger_enabled` and `rails_env` right under `server` (or even `http`)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  root /var/www/apps/example/current/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;

  location / {
      rewrite ^.+ /test permanent;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing now, but all references I find on the web uses two block. Is that outdated information? Both seems to work, so I`m a bit confused.

Comment: Passenger nginx manual http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_passenger_enabled_lt_on_off_gt describes possible places for each directive.